# How to change the style of specific rows in ListView in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview

I have a ListView in my window that I'm binding to a List, Now I want to change the style of specific rows based on the value of that row. Let's say I want the rows that have a certain value in them to have a grey background. How can I do this?

```
<ListView Margin="0 10 0 0" 
            Height="205"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            VerticalAlignment="Top" 
            Width="270"
            Name="ElevationList">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Story" 
            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=El}"
            Width="100"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Depending on the number of outcomes, you could use a custom `IValueConverter`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XAML Code:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
    xmlns:sampleApp="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1">
<Window.Resources>
    <sampleApp:NumberToBGColorConverter x:Key="NumberBGConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ListViewItems}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type sampleApp:Number}">
                <Grid Background="{Binding NumberValue,Converter={StaticResource NumberBGConverter}}" Height="20" Width="250">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding NumberValue}" FontWeight="SemiBold"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

C# Code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private List<Number> m_ListViewItems;

    public List<Number> ListViewItems
    {
        get { return m_ListViewItems; }
        set { m_ListViewItems = value; }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
        ListViewItems = new List<Number>();
        ListViewItems.Add(new Number() { NumberValue = 1 });
        ListViewItems.Add(new Number() { NumberValue = 2 });
        ListViewItems.Add(new Number() { NumberValue = 3 });
        ListViewItems.Add(new Number() { NumberValue = 4 });
    }
}

public class Number
{
    private int m_NumberValue;

    public int NumberValue
    {
        get { return m_NumberValue; }
        set { m_NumberValue = value; }
    }
}

public class NumberToBGColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var number = (int)value;

        if (number % 2 == 0)
            return "Gray";
        else
            return "Yellow";
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```