# MVVM Binding Observable Collection to view?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

In my application, I need to bind a checkbox list to an observable collection. I have seen many examples but I could not find a proper implementation for this and thats why I am posting this question.

The View:

```
<Grid Name="GrdMain" Background="White">    
    <ListView Name="lstConditions" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="150" 
                ItemsSource="{Binding ConditionsModels}" Margin="0,25,0,0" BorderBrush="Transparent" >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <CheckBox Content="{Binding Path=condition}" Margin="8" Style="{StaticResource CheckBoxDefault}"
                                IsChecked="{Binding hasCondition,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                </StackPanel>                    
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>    
    </ListView>
</grid>
```

The model:

```
public class ConditionsModel
{
    public int profileId { get; set; }
    public string condition { get; set; }
    public bool hasCondition { get; set; }
}
```

The View Model:

```
public class ConditionsViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private ConditionsModel _conditionsModel;
    private ObservableCollection<ConditionsModel> _conditionsModels;

    public ConditionsModel ConditionsModel
    {
        get
        {
            return _conditionsModel;
        }
        set
        {
            _conditionsModel = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("ConditionsModel");
        }
    }


    public ObservableCollection<ConditionsModel> ConditionsModels
    {
        get
        {
            return _conditionsModels;
        }
        set
        {
            _conditionsModels = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("ConditionsModels");
        }
    }


    public ConditionsViewModel(int profileId)
    {
        ConditionsModel = new ConditionsModel();
        ConditionsModels = new ObservableCollection<ConditionsModel>();
        ConditionsModels.CollectionChanged += ConditionsModels_CollectionChanged;
        GetConditions(profileId);
    }

    void ConditionsModels_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        RaisePropertyChanged("ConditionsModels");
    }


    private void GetConditions(int profileId)
    {
        HealthAssessmentRepository _rep = new HealthAssessmentRepository();
        _conditionsModels = _rep.GetConditions(profileId);
    }
}
```

Is this a correct implementation? I need to update the model when the user checks or unchecks the checkbox. But its not raising the propery changed event when the check box is checked or unchecked.Should I implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface on the model as well?

I have seen many examples, but all of them has different approaches to this and I am confused. Please show the correct implementation of this?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by _its not raising the propery changed event_? Which property event do you expect it to raise? Change to `hasCondition` won't raise event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` for class `ConditionsModel` and raise `PropertyChangedEvent` for the property you want to observe/synchronize, because it is ViewModel as well.

For class `ConditionsViewModel`, it's the ViewModel of whole `ListView`, for `ConditionsModel`, it's the ViewModel of every line. ViewModel can be overlaid. If `ConditionsModel` is the domain model, my suggestion is that add a new ItemViewModel, because they belong to different layers. It's always better to distinguish the different layers properly.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have missed the **DataType** property within DataTemplate. Just refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27095395/how-to-change-the-style-of-specific-rows-in-listview-in-wpf/27098557#27098557)

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type sampleApp:ConditionsModel}">
```

Here **sampleApp** in the namespace reference created within  tag. And **ConditionsModel** is your model class.

Comment: @sony , Is that enough to make the solution? Or you face any other problem?